# How can i cut a rectangle out of a bitmap

Tags: ios

I want to cut a rectangle from **x= 100, y = 100, width = 50 , height = 50** from an image. and I loaded it from the web into a `UIImageView`. First of all, is it possible to manipulate a loaded image from remote `URL`? If so, what class/method is useful for this ?